# Loading pictures from mounted drives in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mount

I'm looking for a way to display images, which are stored on mounted drives, in a laravel application we are building. As these drives are outside the laravel folder itself I so far have been unable to find a solution as storage doesn't seem to provide such features.

Did anyone already came across this problem or has an idea how this could best be solved?

Comment: You can use a CDN or just have the images able to be accessed in public folder.

Comment: You could symlink it into your laravel directory

Answer (score 0):

As Andrea said a symlink is working like a charm, that way I can create symbolic links to every folder created on these mounted drives.

More info about symlinks can be found here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/